# down to Park and Tilford

Tags: phrase-meaning

> The RCMP are investigating a tire slashing spree in North Vancouver.
>
> More than 150 tires were slashed overnight in the Capilano University
>   area **down** to Park and Tilford according to police.  *(150 tires
>   slashed overnight in North Vancouver - CBC news Dec.4 2014)*

I don't quite understand what '**down**' means here. 
So the slashing happened from somewhere to Park(street) and Tilford(street) in the Capilano University area?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a shortening of the phrase "from (x) all the way down to (y)." The "down" does not imply anything; you will notice a lot of phrases in English have unnecessary directions as qualifiers, such as "up here" (used less often to mean you're above someone than you might think) and "right here." It simply means that the slashed tires begin at Capilano University and continue on towards the crossing of Park and Tilford, two streets.